# Operation queue in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm re-implementing a native app using React Native.
The app uploads video clips to the server, using an operation queue to split the clips and manage the upload process of the file chunks. This queue is active as long as the app is running.

My question is how to approach this issue in React Native - What would be the right way to perform the uploads?